Circular shift of a function.
Consider a function $f$ that maps real numbers to real numbers with domain $[-a,a]$.  I would like to describe the circular shift of this function by an amount $\delta$ such that, if I shift the function to the right, then the values that go to the right of $a$ appear on the left side of the domain and vice versa.
What is the right way to formally define such a circular shift?

Your wording isn’t very clear to me, but maybe something like $$f\left(\frac{2a}{\pi}\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi x+a\delta}{2a}\right)\right)\right)$$ ?

An example graph of the same

That’s amazing.  Thank you.  I had expected “mod”, like in abstract algebra.

You’re welcome. Should I add it as an answer then? Also, I am very curious, where do you find an application for this?

And you’re absolutely correct, we could’ve also used $\operatorname{mod}$. $$f\left(\left(x+\frac{a\delta}{\pi}-a\right)(\operatorname{mod}{2a})-a\right)$$

Please do!  Feel free to add it as an answer.  I’m confused about the second expression.  Is it right to have a pi there?

The range of $\delta$ is from 0 to $2\pi$, the $\pi$ is there to sort of normalize it. Graph

Could you tell where you found an application for this? Or is it just mathematical curiosity?

Oh, I see.  Thank you.  The application is in sampling theory.  It’s a bit complicated to explain in a text; I’ll post a link when I have something written.  Thank you so much for your help!

You’re welcome. :)

If you add an answer, I’ll be happy to mark it correct.  If you provide me your name and anything comes of this, I’ll be happy to acknowledge you. My contact: www.nicholasdwork.com

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

All we need to do is to first map the parameter of the function, in a modular fashion, and then pass it through $f$.
Modifying the parameter can be done in many different ways, like:
$$\left(x+\frac{a\delta}{\pi}-a\right)\left(\operatorname{mod }{2a}\right)-a$$
$$\frac{2a}{\pi}\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi x+a\delta}{2a}\right)\right)$$
Then we can simply pass this modified parameter through the function $f$.
Example graph
